# Airpod pros microphone intermittently does not connect on Macbook Pro and causes headphone disconnect

Tags: bluetooth, mac-pro, airpods

Odd issue that only seems to affect my Airpod Pros on Macbook Pro (2019, 16 inch).  I have used, without issue, other bluetooth headphones with microphone on this computer, and used the airpod pros on other mac laptops and iphone.

The behaviour is like this, but it only happens sometimes, and I haven't found consistent reproduction steps

1. Connect airpod pros to laptop.  This always works, at least in appearances.
2. Attempt to use something that needs the microphone (Zoom, the 'sound'->input system pane, it doesn't seem to matter)
3. The system hangs for a few seconds, sound input reverts back to laptop microphone, and the airpod pros disconnect.

It doesn't always happen, and toggling bluetooth on and off sometimes helps (next time it connects fine) - I've tried different combinations of apps, upgraded to Big Sur (happened before and still happens after upgrade)

Any advice to help track down the problem and solve will be appreciated and upvoted.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my 2017 Macbook pro. It works sometimes but most times it hangs and disconnects. I've been able to find a temporary solution by selecting a separate mic source on Zoom, MS Teams etc.. not ideal at all